# Cannot link with Lua library on Linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, lua

I've compiled Lua 5.2 on Debian x86-64 with make posix, and am trying to compile the following with the command `gcc -ldl -llua main.c`

```
#include "lua.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "lualib.h"
int main() {  
  lua_State *L = luaL_newstate(); 
  luaL_openlibs(L);  
  dofile("test.lua");   
  return 0;
}
```

and get unresolved references to the lua functions

Comment: Including the errors is generally helpful.

Comment: You have to put the libraries last. `gcc main.c -o myprog -llua -ldl`

Comment: @EtanReisner He **did include** the compiler command line... And "undefined reference" errors don't raise out of the linker not finding a library (that would be `cannot find library for -llua`).

Comment: dofile is not a C function, it is a lua function. Presumably you wanted luaL_dofile or similar.

Comment: And -l order matters for inter-object resolution but not for main compilation object resolution as far as I know.

Comment: I'm not home at the moment so I can't copy paste the GCC output, but its just undefined reference for each of the three functions. I've also tried putting the libs last, and in every other order.

Comment: With the luaL_dofile change that code compiles with your gcc command once I add `-lm`.

Comment: as far as i remember, `-lm` is also required. (`libmath`)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your error is

```
undefined reference to `dofile'
```

then your problem is that dofile is a lua function and not a C one.

You probably want `luaL_dofile(L, "test.lua")`.

Comment: Now I get (after adding -lm too)
    /tmp/ccRzfNIp.o: In function main'
    main.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to luaL_newstate'
    main.c:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to luaL_openlibs'
    main.c:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to luaL_loadfilex'
    main.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to lua_pcallk'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Ah. So it would seem that H2CO3's comment before about order does matter here (presumably because this is linking from a static library which is not my normal mode of operation). `gcc -L. -lm -ld test.c -llua` works for me.

Answer (score -1):

The mine command to compile is
gcc -o pp pp.c -I/usr/include/lua5.1/ -llua5.1
maybe is missing the include